# pandas - top count items after groupby on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe data grouped by two columns (X, Y) and then I have count of elements in Z. Idea here is to find the top 2 counts of elements across X, Y.

Dataframe should look like:

```
mostCountYInX = df.groupby(['X','Y'],as_index=False).count()
 C      X   Y     Z
USA    NY  NY    5
USA    NY  BR    14
USA    NJ  JC    40
USA    FL  MI    3
IND    MAH MUM   4
IND    KAR BLR   2
IND    KER TVM   2
CHN    HK  HK    3
CHN    SH  SH    3
```

Individually, I can extract the information I am looking for:

```
XTopCountInTopY = mostCountYInX[mostCountYInX['X'] == 'NY']
XTopCountInTopY = XTopCountInTopY.nlargest(2,'Y')
```

In the above I knew group I am looking for which is X = NY and got the top 2 records. Is there a way to print them together?

Say I am interested in IND and USA then the Output expected:

```
 C     X   Y     Z
USA    NJ  JC    40
USA    NY  BR    14
IND    MAH MUM   4
IND    KAR BLR   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on index with parameter `sort=False` then `apply` using `lambda function` and [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) on `Z` using parameter `ascending=False` then take top 2 values and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) as:

```
mask = df.index.isin(['USA','IND'])
df = df[mask].groupby(df[mask].index,sort=False).\
              apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Z',ascending=False)[:2]).\
              reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
print(df)

       X    Y   Z
USA   NJ   JC  40
USA   NY   BR  14
IND  MAH  MUM   4
IND  KAR  BLR   2
```

**EDIT :** After OP changed the Dataframe:

```
mask = df['C'].isin(['USA','IND'])
df = df[mask].groupby('C',sort=False).\
              apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Z',ascending=False)[:2]).\
              reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
     C    X    Y   Z
0  USA   NJ   JC  40
1  USA   NY   BR  14
2  IND  MAH  MUM   4
3  IND  KAR  BLR   2
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that USA and IND are not index cols.

Comment: if we need to aggregate the count for each of the resulting groups, how do we do that. I think that is missing. I am getting the actual value of Z than the count of records post the grouping.